# java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user after Xampp upgrade

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, xampp

I upgraded my Xampp from xampp-win32-1.8.3-4 to xampp-win32-5.6.3-0 I get:

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'mydbusername'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

when I Clean and Build -> Run my stand-alone project.

The project was running fine, until I upgraded Xampp. Nothing in the code has changed. Where could I be having the problem? Is there something that needs tweaking in xampp-win32-5.6.3-0

Thank you all in advance.

Answer (score 1):

you can change or clear root password in the `config.inc.php` file located in the `xammp\phpMyAdmin`

Comment: The default Xampp user works. The way I'd like working it is by creating a database user, adding privileges to this user then accessing the database via this user. This doesn't work.

Comment: Maybe you didn't give host machine privilages correctly. Please check this link: [link](http://www.codesenior.com/en/tutorial/Xampp-Create-New-User)